# What is the remainder when $1\times 1! + 2\times 2! + 3\times 3! +\ldots+ 11\times 11! + 3$ is divided by $12!$?

Tags: divisibility, factorial

What will be the remainder when $$1\times 1! + 2\times 2! + 3\times 3! +\ldots+ 11\times 11! + 3$$ is divided by $12!$ ?

I found out that the remainder will be same in case of $12!$ as well as $12$, but don't know how?

Kindly help me with this question.

**Note: ! means Factorial**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Notice that$$1*1! + 2*2! + 3*3! +\ldots+ 11*11! + 3=3+\sum_{n=1}^{11}n!*n\\=3+\sum_{n=1}^{11}n!*(n+1-1)\\=3+\sum_{n=1}^{11}(n+1)!-n!\\=3+12!-1=12!+2$$so the remainder is obviously $2$.

Comment: How did you come to the step where $\sum_{n=1}^{11} (n+1)!-n! = 12!$?

Comment: Actually it is $12!-1$ because $\sum_{1}^{11}(n+1)!-n!=12!-11!+11!-10!+10!-9!+\cdots 4!-3!+3!-2!+2!-1!$

Comment: Oh nice. Thanks

Comment: You're welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

Write $1!$ as $(2-1)1!$. Leave out the $-1$ and the rest is a $2!$. Add this to the existing $2*2!$ which makes $3*2!=3!$ and so on with every next term, which means that your sum is $$12!-1+3$$ which means that the remainder is $2$.